# Resizing weirdness in custom View with isFlipped YES

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nssplitview, nsaffinetransform

I'm having a hard time getting my subview to behave properly.

I am using auto-layout. My main window is an `NSSplitView`. One of the views in the split view is a custom view, where I set

```
-(BOOL)isFlipped
{
    return YES;
}
```

An added subview in this view is displayed at the top left. The subview is a lot smaller than the superview, so there is some space left over at the bottom. The problems start when I resize the window (and thus the superview). The subview moves up, out of view, like below. First picture shows the top of the subview nicely aligned at the top of the superview:

[image]

After resizing the window, I get this at the top:

[image]

This should not happen; if anything, the subview should be clipped at the bottom. The top-left of the subview should always stay at the top-left of the superview.

I am sure I made an error somewhere -- does someone recognize this behavior? I am afraid I messed things up a while ago and have no idea where to look. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Added info: The clipping at the top of the superview occurs after resizing the superview. If, after this happens, I remove the subview and add another subview, it is displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after turning "translates mask into constraints" off for the subview:
[image]